# How to export Microsoft Project reports to a file

Tags: microsoft-project

I am using MS Project 2007. I want to export reports that Project can generate. Is there a way to either export a Project report or save it to a file in any format?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Microsoft article:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/project-help/export-project-data-to-another-file-format-HP043007930.aspx?CTT=1